# Adding code to new excel sheet dynamically

Tags: vba, excel, validation, programmatically-created

I need some help Regarding  VBA. 
In My code I  add an excel sheet and rename it and add a validation list to it.I need to run some code on changing value in that validation list.And that must run only on change of that particular cell.
If I am not clear please let me know.Please Help me solving this.

Comment: Start here if you want to add code dynamically to a sheet: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: hi @Tim Williams , For this I need to add Code to particular Sheet. Here I am facing another Problem. I can add code by referencing Sheet Index. And as I am renaming the sheet , and sheet Index and position are always not same, how could I do that. Is there any way of getting Sheet Index. Some function etc.,???

Comment: Can you specify your question further? After adding and renaming a (copied?) sheet, what exactly do you need to add to this sheet? Why?

Comment: Am creating a "NEW" Sheet by calling a macro on Button CLick.So while creation of sheet itself i need to add some  Code  for "Worksheet_change" event

Comment: but is the worksheet_change event pretty much the same for each new sheet? (ps: please reply with @peteralbert, else I will not be notified)

Comment: @peterAlbert Thanks for reply.. I need same functionality for all sheets added by this Button

Comment: then instead of using a the `Worksheet_Change` event, simply use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event - this you only need to place once in ?ThisWorkbook`and it'll handle all worksheets. Just a condition in the beginning of the event, checking if any of the affected worksheet is changed...

Comment: @peteralbert Ok.. But there are few work sheets for which it should not apply.. But I can Use It.  I would be more great full if ou explain me about CodeName variable...

Comment: @peteralbert once i get code variable for new sheet my task is done. But am getting CodeName only after completion of Button Event

Comment: sorry, don't know when `.CodeName` is set. However, in most cases, you can simply address it with `Worksheets("normal name")` or `Sheets(Sheets.Count)` for a newly inserted sheet

Comment: You're welcome! I summarized the comments as an answer for future readers. If it helped, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of trying to create the individual code for each new worksheet with the Visual Basic Extensibility (see [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) for further reading), simply use the Workbook wide event `Workbook_SheetChange` (you need to place it in the `ThisWorkbook`module).

In this event code first check, if the worksheet which caused the event is one of the newly created worksheets. This can be done most easily, be checking the `.Name` of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SelectionChange` Event and `Change` event or it is also possible to use the event `Thisworkbook` module. `SheetChange` or `SheetSelectionChange`.