# Adding a VBA code in a new Sheet Code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to use the "Workbook_SheetChange" where the code is written in the ThisWorkbook code or in a separate module but works on a another sheet.
The sheets are created by another macro and data is uploaded and processed separately, i don't know the number of sheets that will be create.
Is there a way i can use "Workbook_SheetChange" :
    - when the code is written in a separate module
    - or to copy the code automatically when the new sheet is created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082722/adding-code-to-new-excel-sheet-dynamically

Comment: Not sure what you're after - sounds like a Change event that will work on all sheets?  Just add your code to the `Workbook_SheetChange` event in the Thisworkbook module and it will doing what it sounds like you're asking.  e.g. Add this code to the ThisWorkbook module:  `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range): MsgBox Sh.Name & " " & Target.Address: End Sub` - whenever you change a value on _any_ sheet it will tell you the sheet name and the cell address.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is a duplicate of [Adding code to new excel sheet dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082722/adding-code-to-new-excel-sheet-dynamically), but it might still require some explanation.

In VBA, the event Workbook_SheetChange will fire on every worksheet change. So if you want to run 2 different procedures you can do something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _ 
 ByVal Source As Range) 
 If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" then
     'Do one thing
 Else
     'Do another
 End If
End Sub
```

This is much better than "writing code that writes code."

Now if you're creating a new workbook it gets harder - let us know if that's what you need.

Comment: @MacroMan ... you are absolutely correct, and I am absolutely wrong! What I said is true about _Access_ but not Excel. Editing so that no one listens to my incorrect advice!

Comment: Thank you for all the responses but i have tried this, if the code is in the specific sheet code with "Worksheet_" it works perfectly but when it is in the workbook code it doesn't. i some times get an error or it does nothing. Run-time Error -2147417848 (80010108) Method 'Cells' of object '_worksheet' failed

Comment: I the end all works best.
 I found that double clicking works beater for me :
[Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)]